# Linking problem to libraries installed with Homebrew since Mojave update

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, gsl

I have recently updated to Mojave and since then am experiencing linking problems to libraries (gsl, Cuba etc.) that I had installed with Homebrew. 
When compiling my code, gcc (tried g++-6 and g++-8, also installed with brew) does not seem to search the directories where brew stores the header files for those libraries. The code compiled when I manually set the paths to

```
GSL_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/gsl/
GSL_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
CUBA_PATH=/usr/local/include/
```

**But since I am using this in all my make-files I do not want to do this every time**...
Before I was using Sierra and I have included in my .bash_profile the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

This seemed to do the trick before. But now /usr/local/sbin did not exist anymore. I ran brew doctor which suggested:

You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks /usr/local/sbin
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks /usr/local/sbin

I did just that and reinstalled the libraries but it did not sort out the issue.

I have tried to include 
export `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/include:/usr/local/lib:$PATH`

in the bash-profile, but that did not help either. (Maybe I did it wrong, I am not familiar with setting paths) At this point I am not sure whether brew installs the libraries in a weird place or if gcc just does not look in the correct location.

I have installed Xcode and the command tools. I have tried everything I found (and could understand) that I found as solutions for related problems.

**I would like for gcc to look in the directories that brew installs the libraries to by default.**
I would be really grateful for a suggestion of a clean fix for this issue.

Please excuse the long essay; if you need additional information please do tell, this ist my first time asking for help here.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072318/cannot-link-any-c-program-with-gcc-on-mac-mojave  Mojave seems to have affected a few things that need to be updated.