# Cannot link any C program with gcc on Mac Mojave

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, macports, macos-mojave

I've just updated to OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave) and now, after upgrading Xcode and migrating MacPorts, even the simplest C program will not link with any gcc version. For example, linking the program

```
int main() {}
```

gives:

```
dcs16> gcc test.c 
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using gcc 6.5 in /opt/local/bin:

```
dcs16> gcc --version
gcc (MacPorts gcc6 6.5.0_4) 6.5.0
```

The Xcode version is 11.0 and I have installed the package (which was recommended for solving some compile problems that other people had):

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: There is no problem linking with clang.

Note gcc search dirs are:

```
test> gcc -print-search-dirs
install: /opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/
programs: =/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/bin/
libraries: =/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/lib/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/:/opt/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/6.5.0/../../../
```

Comment: Could you try running `sudo port upgrade gcc6`.

Comment: @Mihir I had done that and gcc5 did not work as well.

Comment: Does `clang` work correctly?

Comment: @Mihir clang works fine. It is just gcc.

Comment: Check out [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave/).  There's a decent chance the answer will assist you.

Comment: As per [mailing lists](https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-users/2019-September/047395.html), installing old cmd line tools may help. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode

Comment: @Mihir  Unfortunately I had already installed the cmd line tools and this did not help. Interestingly enough the system version of gcc in /usr/bin/ works fine. It is just the macports version.

Comment: That `/usr/bin/gcc` is actually the `clang` provided by the Xcode command line tools.  Why aren't you using those tools anyway?

Comment: @DavidS, macOS doesn't have any gcc in real. `cc`, `gcc` and `clang` are all `clang`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Interesting. I did not know this. In any case, I need to compile a lot of code including some Fortran modules which clang cannot handle.

Comment: OK, well it sounds like your installation of gcc is broken if it does not have `/usr/lib` in its standard library paths.  How about removing macports and trying homebrew instead?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes I might break down and try homebrew at some point. Interestingly enough, a coworker who also compiles on his mac is having exactly the same problem so it is not just my machine.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `gcc` was configured to use with `gcc -print-search-dirs`.

Comment: @trojanfoe OK I added this info to the post.

Comment: Looks like this problem has been reported to MacPorts: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/59083

Comment: Yeah I don't see `/usr/lib` on there.  That is weird.

Answer (score 3):

Adding "-L/usr/lib" solves the problem.

Also downgrading from Xcode 11.0 to Xcode 10.3 solves the problem! Note: I also checked Xcode 11.1 which just came out but the problem still exists with 11.1.

Note added: Another programmer informs me that upgrading to OSX 10.15 solves the problem. So this is an incompatibility between OSX 10.14 and Xcode 11.

[Added 28/12/2020] And another programmer informs me that he ran into this problem with Xcode 12.3. His solution was to downgrade to 12.2.

Comment: Which is a hack.

Comment: @trojanfoe I just edited the answer to give a better solution.